# Comparar valores alterados em array de objetos

Tags: javascript

Galera preciso fazer uma comparação entre dois array de objetos pra poder retornar uma classe css e informar qual campo foi alterado.

o resultado esperado seria assim:

VALOR ANTERIOR ----------------------------------  VALOR ATUAL

nome: Rafael   ---------------------------------- nome: Rafael

idade: 29 --------------------------------------- **idade: 30**

Estou tentando

```
valorAtual.find(v1 => valorAnterior.find(v2 => v2.nome == v1.nome && v2.idade != v1.idade return 'campo-alterado')).
```

Mas o resultado não é o esperado.

Comment: Opa Leo, então preciso comparar dois arrays de objetos, pois será um registro de log como era antes e como ficou agora, os arrays estão chegando assim: array1 [{key: rafael, value: 29}], array2 [{key: rafael, value: 30}], e na tela eu vou colocar um do lado do outro e passar um background no campo que estiver com valores diferente, então eu preciso de uma logica que irá retornar minha classe com o background ou retornar vazio

Answer (score 0):

Se você precisa de um modo generico simplesmente para saber se houve alguma mudança no objeto, você pode transformar o mesmo em uma String e então comparar o valor das Strings, exemplo:

```
JSON.stringify(valorAtual) === JSON.stringify(valorAnterior)
```

Se este não for o caso ou você precisar de alguma solução mais "sofisticada" para o problema, por favor adicione mais detalhes e especifique o seu problema de uma maneira mais clara.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode percorrer os arrays e depois percorrer cada atributo dos objetos e comparar os valores conforme abaixo. Os arrays tem que possuir o mesmo tamanho e os objetos os mesmos atributos, o que parece ser o seu caso.

```js
    var array1 = [{key: 'rafael', sobrenome: 'silva', value: 29}],
    array2 = [{key: 'rafael', sobrenome: 'souza', value: 30}],
    i,
    atributo,
    size = array1.length;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { // para percorrer os arrays
        for (atributo in array1[i]) { // para percorrer os atributos dos objetos dos arrays
            if (array1[i][atributo] !== array2[i][atributo]) { // comparação do valor de cada atributo
                // faz alguma coisa com as informações
                console.log(('Diferentes: ' + atributo + ': ' + array1[i][atributo] + ' - ' + array2[i][atributo]));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Para comparar dois arrays de objetos e verificar quais campos foram alterados, você pode criar um loop para percorrer os dois arrays e comparar os valores de cada objeto.

Por exemplo, veja o código abaixo, que compara dois arrays de objetos do tipo Pessoa e retorna um array de strings com os campos alterados:

```
class Pessoa {
  constructor(nome, idade) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.idade = idade;
  }
}

// Cria os dois arrays de objetos
const array1 = [new Pessoa("Rafael", 29), new Pessoa("João", 25)];
const array2 = [new Pessoa("Rafael", 30), new Pessoa("João", 25)];

// Cria o array de campos alterados
const camposAlterados = [];

// Percorre os dois arrays comparando os objetos
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  const obj1 = array1[i];
  const obj2 = array2[i];
  if (obj1.nome !== obj2.nome) {
    camposAlterados.push("nome");
  }
  if (obj1.idade !== obj2.idade) {
    camposAlterados.push("idade");
  }
}

// Imprime os campos alterados
console.log(camposAlterados);
```

Nesse exemplo, o código percorre os dois arrays de objetos comparando os valores dos atributos nome e idade de cada objeto. Caso os valores sejam diferentes, o nome do atributo é adicionado à array de campos alterados.